# Ocaml This '(' might be unmatched

Tags: ocaml

new to Ocaml. I've no clue what is happening here and I've been trying to solve this for maybe 2 hours.

Here is the code:

```
let hailstorm n = 
    match n with
    | (mod n 2 == 0) -> (n/2)
    | (mod n 2 == 1) -> (3*n+1);;
```

When I try to compile it says:

```
File "./x.ml", line 3, characters 11-12:Error: Syntax error: ')' expected
File "./x.ml", line 3, characters 6-7:
Error: This '(' might be unmatched
```

Comment: Did you mean to `match mod n 2 with | 0 -> …; 1 -> …;`?

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `mod` is a binary operator (like `lsl`, `lsr`, `asr`, `land`, `lor`, `lxor` and `or`) . For instance,

```
let zero = 2 mod 2
```

Binary operator can be transformed into standard function by wrapping them around parentheses,

```
let zero = (mod) 2 2
```

this is why the parser is expecting a closing parenthesis after `(mod` .

Then, you pattern matching is wrong because `n mod 2 == 0` is an expression, not a pattern (and you should use structural equality `=` rather than physical equality `==`):

```
let f n = match n mod 2 with
| 0 -> ...
| _ -> ...
```

or

```
let f n = match n mod 2 = 0 with
| true -> ...
| false -> ...
```

which is probably simpler with an `if ... then ... else ...` .